# scrapy import .py files from django has import error

Tags: python, django, scrapy

This is my structure,I have a django project named `kkpro`
in kkpro,I have a django app called `myapp` .
And a scrapy project called `project1` inder the `kkpro/scrapy/music`

```
├── kkpro
    ├── manage.py
    ├── savepage.py
    ├── myapp
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    └── kkpro
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── settings.py
        ├── urls.py
        └── wsgi.py

    │── ── scrapy
    │        ├──music
    │            ├──project1
    │                 ├── scrapy.cfg   
    │                 ├──project1
    │                       ├── __init__.py
    │                       ├── items.py
    │                       ├── pipelines.py
    │                       ├── settings.py
```

this is my `project1/settings.py`

```
import sys, os
path_django_site = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../../../../") 
sys.path.append(path_django_site)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'kkpro.settings'  
import save_page
```

in my computer it works well to used `kkpro` setting,
but when I deploy to aws eb , `import save_page` has error

I edit to `from kali import save_page`. still has error  `ImportError: cannot import name save_page`

What should I do ?
Please help me,thank you very much

Comment: Maybe your `os.path.dirname(__file__)` is pointing to:
/Projects/kkpro/scrapy/music/project1/project1/setings.py

With the "../../../../" points to /Projects/kkpro/scrapy and shoud point to /Projects/kkpro

Can u tell the value of `path_django_site`